# tool to test asynchronously loaded scripts in javascript

Tags: javascript, testing, asynchronous, requirejs

I'm giving my first steps with single wep page apps and RequireJs, and I noticed that quite often everything seems to work find locally, but when deployed on a remote server some errors appears at random, mainly because of async files being loaded and dependencies not being well defined.

(here's just an example https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/requirejs/skOZCi-3nFU/discussion)

I was wondering if there is some kind of tool that could run automated tests but forcing every script to be delayed, trying all possible combinations (I was thinking about some kind of proxy)...

If there's no such thing, how do you test these kind of scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [boilerplatejs](http://boilerplatejs.org/). This is a reference architecture which we are using with our single page java script applications. This will help you to manage your code in a more efficient manner. Have a look.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I'm also trying to come out with my own boiler plate app using backbone and requireJs, have a look at it: https://github.com/opensas/BackboneBootstrap